# Creating normalized tables from a single de-normalized table

Tags: sql-server, join

Alright, bear with me as I try to explain this as clearly as possible.

I have a legacy data table from dBASE currently in SQL that I need to break apart into normalized tables. The legacy table has columns for LastName, FirstName, SSN, TestDate, Score, TestDate2, Score2, TestDate3, Score3. When the old system was in use, and an operator needed to add an additional test, they had to create an entirely new record with the same LastName, FirstName, SSN to enter the fourth test since each record only has a spot for three exams. The new database has an employee table for the LastName, FirstName, and SSN, and a Test table for each of the exams. I can't figure out how to write the procedure in order to get the unique instance of the employee, along with all test records, when it has more than one row associated with it.

Here is an "example" of the data...
[image]

A point in the right direction would be a huge help! Thank you!!

Edit: SQL Server 2012, Employee table currently has an EmployeeId which will be used as the IDENTITY field. The Exam table has the EmployeeId as an FK.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What is the structure of the new tables? Does it have an EmployeeId now? Is that IDENTITY?

Comment: Sorry, Martin, I've edited the OP to answer those questions.

Comment: In your restructuring you should also stop storing SSN in plain text. It should be encrypted.

Comment: I'm not storing SSN in plain text, it is encrypted via the app server in the initial load. This is just sample data.

Comment: When moving a given test to one of these new tables how do you know which test goes to what table? Is there a reason you can't put all the tests in a single table with an identifier so you know which test it is? You seem to have gone from one denormalized structure to a different one. If you keep each test in its own table you will have to change all your queries to include the new test table and create a new table just like all the other test tables every time there is a new test.

Comment: I understand about the sample data. It just makes me cringe when I see SSN in plain text. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not have explained it clearly, that's my fault. There is only one "Test" table that holds all the tests. It doesn't matter if it is coming from the Test1, Test2, or Test3 columns in the legacy data, it all goes into the same Test table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the following

```
INSERT INTO Employee
            (LastName,
             FirstName,
             SSN)
SELECT DISTINCT LastName,
                FirstName,
                SSN
FROM   Denormalised

INSERT INTO Test
            (EmployeeId,
             TestDate,
             TestScore)
SELECT E.EmployeeId,
       CA.TestDate,
       CA.TestScore
FROM   Denormalised D
       JOIN Employee E
         ON EXISTS(SELECT E.LastName,
                          E.FirstName,
                          E.SSN
                   INTERSECT /*Null safe equality in case any of the columns are nullable*/
                   SELECT D.LastName,
                          D.FirstName,
                          D.SSN)
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TestDate,
                           Score
                    UNION ALL /*Unpivot the three test instances into a row each*/
                    SELECT TestDate2,
                           Score2
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT TestDate3,
                           Score3) CA(TestDate, TestScore)
WHERE  NOT ( CA.TestDate IS NULL
             AND CA.TestScore IS NULL )
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I modified it to work flawlessly. Thank you very much for your assistance.